# Store user credentials in PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova

**Hi I am new to phoneGap**. Previously I had been making native android apps. I have been looking out there for a while and could not find best and simplest solution to my problem.

In native android, I used to store user credentials and any sensitive information in SharedPrefs. 
How to achieve (Or even what is the best practice) in phonegap for this ? 
I have read phonegap docs, many places they tend to store such info in sqlite. That's fine, but what if the DB upgrades and or even if application is updated and the data is lost and the user has to login again.

Any solutions which would be simple across all phonegap supported platforms are highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen [this plugin](https://github.com/macdonst/AppPreferences)? I had to modify it slightly to fit my needs but it sounds like it's what your looking for. It interacts with the SharedPrefs.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) But what about ios ? does it work smooth over there ?
P.S: I have no experience in ios development. Since these are .java stuff, does this work with ios ? Because I think they deal with object c ??

Comment: Why not store it in `localstorage`? As long as you are on or past Cordova 2.5 I believe then your data will persist through app updates. The only time it would be lost is if you removed it programmatically or they deleted the application. And since `localstorage` is a HTML5 API it will be supported on all modern platforms without having to use a plugin or get into Java/Objective-C. You can read more about it [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage).

Comment: Cool :) I think this will do. Thanks a lot @AndrewLively !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Andrew Lively Mentioned in the comment above, I used [local storage](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage). This seems to work awesome.

It is super simple.
For those who just want to get started,

**get keyname by index**
var keyName = window.localStorage.key(0);

**put a value**
window.localStorage.setItem("key", "value");

**get a value by key**
var value = window.localStorage.getItem("key");

**remove a value by key**
window.localStorage.removeItem("key");

**flush local storage/all key value pairs**
window.localStorage.clear();

Comment: This isn't secure method of storing user credentials. There must be a storage plugin for android to store in a secure place within the operating system.